# How to catch any exceptions during batch file execution of a python script?

Tags: python, shell, batch-file

I have a batch file scheduled to run a python script every morning. The script is supposed to append to a .csv file. However, some days no data is appended to the csv file which I believe is due to an error during execution of the script. Is there anything I can add to my batch file to save any error messages that cause the script to stop execution to a .txt file? Or is there a better way to do this within the python script instead? Right now in my batch file I just have

```
python "C:\filepath\pythonscript.py"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append redirection to command line, as displayed bellow:

`python "C:\filepath\pythonscript.py" 2>>log.txt`

`2>>log.txt` statement redirect STDERR (errors printed by python interpreter) to a log file in APPEND mode (single > will switch to OVERWRITE mode). If you want to capture STDOUT too, change added apendix to `>>log.txt 2>&1`